# If a 32 bit CPU has a 64bit bus system, is it 64 bit or 32 bit?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-architecture, cpu-speed, cpu-architecture

Let's say the internal registers of a CPU are 32 bits wide. But the CPU has a 64 bit system bus and the  two separate pipelines are receiving information simultaneously, is it considered a 32bit processor or a 64 bit processor?

Comment: A nice subject for discussion. We have at least 1) internal register width. 2) Data width to external memory.  3) Number of address lines for the memory.  Personally I would select #1 (so a 386SX with 16 bit data width) would still be a 32 bit CPU and a 68000 (32 bit internally, 24 bits to select memory addresses and 16 bit data width to the memory would both count as a 32 bit CPU.

Comment: What would a 32-bit CPU miss on a 64-bit system system? Is it more than 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things having to do with a CPU that can be X-bits.

The old Motorola 68000 came in an 8-bit bus variant, the 68008, for example.  It was a 16-bit CPU however, though the argument could be made it was 32-bit.

Even the registers or internal mechanics don't tell the whole story.

- The Z-80 is generally considered an 8-bit CPU (opcodes were 8 bits wide), but many of its instructions combine register parts to all 16-bit indexed access to things like a 16-bit CPU.
- I don't think there was an 8-bit CPU in wide use that actually had 8 address lines (allowing access to 256 bytes of RAM only).  The classic 8-bit CPUs typically had 16 address lines and could address 64K of RAM/ROM.  (Not the CPU in the Atari 2600, though, it was limited to 4K).
- The CP1610 (the CPU in the old Intellivision game system) supposedly used 10-bit opcodes (some instructions requiring 16 bits to encode spread over 20 bits - not sure if this was aligned on bytes or not) but was otherwise considered a 16-bit system (don't let anyone tell you the Sega Genesis was the first 16-bit home game system!)

But programmers (who are the ones spending the most face time with the CPU's innards) don't really care about the hardware interface between CPU and memory, they care about the interface presented via the CPU's instruction set, and this question becomes the most important:  *What's the number of bits that registers and instructions deal with at once*.

`i386` instruction set prefers to deal with 32-bit quantities, if you need to do math on integer quantities greater than 32 bits, you need to add the lower 32 bits first, then carry over into a second 32 bits.  But `i386` is flexible and lets you add 16 or 8 bit quantities as well, as well as split registers up into 16-bit or 8-bit sections.

[image]

The "long" mode aka "64-bit" mode, aka `amd64` instruction set tacks on another 32 bits to these registers, but all the old instructions that address 32, 16, or 8 bit parts of registers are still there.

[image]

So how is that related to the bus?  It isn't.  As long as the bus gets the data from the CPU to the RAM, the programmer doesn't care.  Obviously a narrower bus is going to be slower, but it won't affect how the programmer tells the CPU to do things (other than maybe trying to make the program access memory more efficiently.)

It makes sense to have at least as many bus bits as CPU bits but this does not have to be the case.  The bus width doesn't have to have anything to do with the CPU instruction set or its registers.

Therefore, @Eugen Rieck's answer is really correct.

Answer (score 3):

It is a 32 Bit CPU - there is widespread consent, that the "Bitness" of a CPU is the width of a `void *`, which in this case would be 32